# How to add or remove elment from arraye if exists or not

Tags: php

add element to array if not exists and remove it if exists

```
 <?php
$hackers = array ('Alan Kay', 'Peter Norvig', 'Linus Trovalds', 'Larry Page');

AddOrRemove('Sezar mbar',$hackers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like

```
function AddOrRemove($val,&$hackers) {

    $index = array_search($val,$hackers);
    if($index === false) {
        $hackers[] = $val;
    } else {
        unset($hackers[$index]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following code:

```
<?php
$hackers = array ('Alan Kay', 'Peter Norvig', 'Linus Trovalds', 'Larry Page');
if(in_array('Sezar mbar',$hackers))   // if value is in array
{
  if(($key = array_search('Sezar mbar', $hackers)) !== false) {   // find the key and delete the value
    unset($hackers[$key]);
  }
}
else   // if value is not in array
{
   array_push($hackers,'Sezar mbar');   // push value into the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Mac", $os)) {
    $os = array_diff($os, array('Mac'));
}else
{
    array_push($os,"Mac");
}
var_dump($os);
```

Hope this will help you.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$hackers = array ('Alan Kay', 'Peter Norvig', 'Linus Trovalds', 'Larry Page');

function AddOrRemove($text, $array) {

  $exists = false;
  $index = 0;

  for ($i=0; $i< count($array); $i++){
        if ($array[$i] == $text){ $exists = true; $index = $i; break; }        
  }

  if ($exists){
    unset($array[$i]);
  }
  else {
    array_push($array, $text);
  }

  echo count($array);
}

AddOrRemove('Sezar mbar',$hackers);
```